# The program 'c:\...\a.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000)

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code

I'm new to vscode editor and I want to run simple C project like below, but when I was run this debug console says like below. I want to know how to run this proper way.

```
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
[New Thread 3076.0x2314]
[New Thread 3076.0x20c4]
Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, 0x00401603 in main ()
[Thread 3076.0x20c4 exited with code 0]
[Inferior 1 (process 3076) exited normally]
The program 'c:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Example\a.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).
```

(this is test.c file )

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hellow world");
    return 0;

}
```

I was configured tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "build Hello"
        }
    ]   
}
```

And this is launch.json code I was configured:

```
{    
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

This is my c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
{
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/test.c",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++//tr1",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/test.c",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++//tr1"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
```

Comment: You `return 0` and are surprised that the program is returning 0? What's going on

Comment: What part of **Inferior 1 (process 3076) exited normally** is confusing to you? **exited normally** seems really clear and self-explanatory.

Comment: If by "proper way" you mean outside of the IDE, just open up a command prompt and enter in the program filename.

Comment: Which part of the output exactly bothers you?

Answer (score 1):

It's just trying to tell you that all went fine. Return value 0 is "no error".

You have a typo in "hello" though, the trailing "w" shouldn't be there.

And `main()`'s parameters should be either `(void)` or `(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: More precisely, it is the value you yourself returned in the return statement of `main`: `return 0;` :-)

Comment: @RiyazMubarak Once more: There is no error. Everything went fine.